# Assign random colours from array to wp category list

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I've followed articles on here to assign a random border colour to an element from an array of colours. It works but I'd like to assign a different colour to each instance of the element. The elements in question are a a list of categories generated by the `get_categories()` function.

As you'll see from the below, Ive tried to implement `.each()` within the jQuery in the vein hope that it might work.. however it still just applies the same value to all instances of the element with the class `slate` .

code:

```
$taxonomy     = 'range';
$show_count   = false;
$pad_counts   = false;
$hierarchical = true;
$title        = '';
$style        = 'list'; 
$term         = get_queried_object();

$args = array(
  'taxonomy'     => $taxonomy,
  'show_count'   => $show_count,
  'pad_counts'   => $pad_counts,
  'hierarchical' => $hierarchical,
  'title_li'     => $title,
  'style'        => $style, 
  'walker'       => null,
  'number'       => null,
  'hierarchical' => 1,  
  'hide_empty'   => 0,
  'use_desc_for_title' => 1,    
);

$categories = get_categories($args);

?>

    <?php if($categories){
    echo '<div class="col-2-3 push-1-6 clearfix">';
    foreach($categories as $category) {
        echo '<div class="col-1-3 prod-cat-block clearfix"> ';
        $image = get_field('featured_image', 'category_'.$category->term_id);
        $url = get_category_link( $category->term_id );
        echo '<a href="' . $url . '"> <img src="' . $image['url'] . '" />'; 
        echo '<div class="slate"><h2 class="cat-title ugly white-txt slate-bk">' . $category->name . '</h2></div></a>';
        echo '</div>';
    } 
    echo '</div>';
}
```

jQuery:

```
    var colors = ['#2d45a9', '#c7d053', '#0db3db', '#ca3737', '#5392ba'];
    var random_color = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
    j$('.slate').each(function(){j$(this).css('border-color', random_color);});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this directly in php why are you using jquery.

Kindly check below code for the same.

```
 $colorarray=array("red","green","yellow"); // color array


  if($categories){
     echo '<div class="col-2-3 push-1-6 clearfix">';
     foreach($categories as $category) {

            $colorkey= array_rand($colorarray,1); // get random key
            $colorval=$colorarray[$colorkey]; // get array value

            echo '<div class="col-1-3 prod-cat-block clearfix"> ';
            $image = get_field('featured_image', 'category_'.$category->term_id);
            $url = get_category_link( $category->term_id );
            echo '<a href="' . $url . '"> <img src="' . $image['url'] . '" />'; 
            echo '<div class="slate '.$colorval.'"><h2 class="cat-title ugly white-txt slate-bk">' . $category->name . '</h2></div></a>';
            echo '</div>';
       } 
       echo '</div>';
   }
```

Comment: IMHO this is the better solution.

Comment: though, I would probably improve it, by saving the last color used and skipping that key, so it doesn't take `red` two+ times in a row.

Answer (score 0):

A dirty, but do able, solution would be:

```
$random = rand(1, 5);

switch ($random):
    case 1:
        return '#2d45a9'; // blue
        break;
    case 2:
        return '#c7d053'; // yellow
        break;
    case 3:
        return '#0db3db'; // light blue
        break;
    case 4:
        return '#ca3737'; // red
        break;
    case 5:
        return '#5392ba'; // another blue
        break;
endswitch;
```

You could put this into a function, so the color will be returned as text and could be reused for other ends.

**Documentation `rand()`:**

> http://php.net/manual/en/function.rand.php

**Documentation `Switch`:**

> http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php

**Edit:**

Perhaps you want to have a `jQuery` solution instead of `PHP`. But this is just another way to make it happen.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you do the `random` function only once, and apply the value to all of the elements in the `each` loop. You should do the `random` inside the loop, so that every element will get a different value.

```
j$('.slate').each(function(){
   var random_color = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
   j$(this).css('border-color', random_color);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var colors = ['#2d45a9', '#c7d053', '#0db3db', '#ca3737', '#5392ba'];   
j$('.slate').each(function(){
    var random_color = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
    j$(this).css('border-color', random_color);
});
```

You need to re-random the color inside the foreach loop.

Fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/386wvujL/4/)